# Scroll to the top of page after error message

Tags: error, input, scroll

When I add something into input field and have message like "This field is required" the page will scroll to the top and shows these error messages. Maybe it comes from class mage-error, but I'm not sure. How to prevent scrolling to the top? Maybe some js code I need to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with a mixin to avoid overwriting the whole file:

```
1) app/design/frontend/[THEME_VENDOR]/[THEME_NAME]/Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js
```

var config = {
config: {
mixins: {
'mage/validation': {
'Magento_Theme/js/lib/mage/validation-mixin': true
}
}
}
};

2. `app/design/frontend/[THEME_VENDOR]/[THEME_NAME]/Magento_Theme/web/js/lib/mage/validation-mixin.js`

define([
'jquery'
], function ($) {
'use strict';

```
    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.validation', widget, {
            /**
             * Handle form validation. Focus on first invalid form field.
             *
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             * @param {Object} validation
             */
            listenFormValidateHandler: function (event, validation) {
                let firstActive = $(validation.errorList[0].element || []),
                    lastActive = $(validation.findLastActive() ||
                        validation.errorList.length && validation.errorList[0].element || []),
                    parent, windowHeight, successList;

                if (lastActive.is(':hidden')) {
                    parent = lastActive.parent();
                    windowHeight = $(window).height();
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: parent.offset().top - windowHeight / 2
                    });
                }

                // ARIA (removing aria attributes if success)
                successList = validation.successList;

                if (successList.length) {
                    $.each(successList, function () {
                        $(this)
                            .removeAttr('aria-describedby')
                            .removeAttr('aria-invalid');
                    });
                }

                if (firstActive.length) {
                    /* vertically center the first field on the screen. This is best for UX but if you prefer to avoid the scrolling completelly, just remove the next line and the function "scrollToCenterFormFieldOnError" below. */
                    scrollToCenterFormFieldOnError(firstActive);
                    firstActive.focus();
                }
            }
        });

        function scrollToCenterFormFieldOnError(firstActive) {
            let fieldTop = firstActive.offset().top,
                fieldHeight = firstActive.height(),
                windowHeight = $(window).height(),
                offset;

            offset = fieldTop - ((windowHeight / 2) - (fieldHeight / 2));

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: offset
            });
        }

        return $.mage.validation;
    }
});
```

**Update**
***** Second Way ****

**Copy**

> MAGENTO_ROOT/**vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/validation.js**
>
> into **app/design/frontend/THEME_ROOT/web/mage/**

then delete (start in line 1956)

```
if (firstActive.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: firstActive.offset().top
    });
    firstActive.focus();
}
```

become

```
if (firstActive.length) {                   
   firstActive.focus();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, after this implementation nothing was changing :(

Comment: Your mixin is working?

Comment: How I can check if the mixin works?

Comment: Updated answer added another way , follow that

Comment: Thank you so much!!